# Pandas skiprows beyond 900000 fails

Tags: python, pandas

My csv file contains 6Million records and I am trying to split it into multiple smaller sized files by using **skiprows**.. My Pandas version is '0.12.0' and the code is

```
pd.read_csv(TRAIN_FILE, chunksize=50000, header=None, skiprows=999999, nrows=100000)
```

It works as long as skiprows is less than 900000. Any idea if it is expected ? If I do not use skiprows, my nrows can go upto 5Million records. Have not yet tried beyond that. will try this also.

*tried csv splitter, but it does not work properly for the first entry, may be, because, each cell consists of multiple lines of code etc.*

**EDIT**: I am able to split it into csv by reading the entire 7GB file using pandas read_csv and writing in parts to multiple csv files.

Comment: Why not use `csv` module? You'll be able to split the file without reading it into memory. It might be slower, but unless you have some kind of super HDD you'll be IO-bound anyways.

Comment: Are you able to try the latest version of pandas? There have been changes to this area in 0.13 and in current master.

Comment: Pandas puts everything into memory. Are you sure your not running out of memory over 900000?

Comment: a) What does 'fails' mean? MemoryError? Post the entire stacktrace. b) Yes sometimes it might be preferable workaround to just manually skip the first n rows. That's a simple while-loop.

Comment: and c) as with any software under active development, update to the current (0.14.1, July 2014) then retry; they may have fixed your bug already. 0.12.0 is pretty ancient by now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you are specifying both `nrows` and `chunksize`. At least in pandas 0.14.0 using

```
pandas.read_csv(filename, nrows=some_number, chunksize=another_number)
```

returns a `Dataframe` (reading the whole data), whereas

```
pandas.read_csv(filename, chunksize=another_number)
```

returns a TextFileReader that loads the file lazily.

Splitting a csv then works like this:

```
for chunk in pandas.read_csv(filename, chunksize=your_chunk_size):
    chunk.to_csv(some_filename)
```